# how to Spool a file with name that contains timestamp in sql script?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to spool data from database into a file and I want the filename to have timestamp in it. For example if my file name is `myData.csv` I need to create a file like `myData_08082015.csv`. I am passing the timestamp as an argument. But I don't know how to concatenate this with the file name. I tried `spool $HOME_DIR/myData_&1.csv` but its working strangely. How to do it?

This is how I am executing it in sqlplus prompt
`@$HOME_DIR/te.sql 18927346`
`Session altered.`
`Session altered.`
`Session altered.`
`Session altered.`
And the file I am getting is 
`myData;csv.lst`

Comment: Please show your call to the script and what the output looks like.

Comment: I have edited the question. That is how I am running it from sqlplus prompt.

Comment: this may help https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:3581757800346555562